# Concatenate lists for a given key in mustache template

Tags: ios, mustache

Here's what my data looks like (YAML):

```
-
name: objectA
components:
  - 
    name: "component_1"
  - 
    name: "component_2"

styles:
  -
    name: "new style"
    components:
    -
        name: "component_1"
  -
    name: "other style"
    components:
    -
        name: "component_4"
```

I would like to retrieve in my mustache the full list of components for objectA, meaning i need to access all the components children values and concatenate them or uniq them.
The goal would be to have a template like this:

```
{{#allComponents}}
{{name}}
{{/allComponents}}
```

which should output:

```
component_1
component_2
component_4
```

PS: i am using GRMustache

Answer (score 0):

There's very little chance any Mustache implementation could handle such a specific need with any native built-in syntax of any kind. And GRMustache does actually not.

The simplest path is to prepare your `allComponents` key before rendering your data.

Comment: I was afraid of that, thanks anyway. oh would the ViewModel simplify this (having a method allComponents)?

Comment: Oh, yes, you can write your own `allComponents` method. The main point is to provide this key to the template. You can achieve this by transforming the YAML object, or by defining the allComponents key in your ViewModel object. Pick your preferred way.